# Matching a RegEx text string that includes parentheses

Tags: regex

I'm a novice in regex, wondering is there a way to match a text string that includes parentheses? For example, if a text string matches the characters `abc (123)` want to output the text `ABC title 123`.

We tried the following regex but there was not output because text string included `()` characters:

```
WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.&#42;abc (123).&#42;')) THEN "ABC 23"
```

Note, the same expression was working if text string didn't contain ( ) characters, so the text string `def 123` did generate the output `DEF 123`

```
WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.&#42;def 123.&#42;')) THEN "DEF 123"
```

Any idea what regex expression we can use?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but generally speaking, you need to escape parentheses (when you want to use them literally) because they have a special meaning in regex. So, instead of `(something)`, you'd write `\(something\)`.

Comment: [Google Data Studio](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax); [PostgresSQL (section 9.7.3.1)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html); If you're using something else, better specify it in the question

Comment: is this oracle db? please tag the question with the language/too/databasel you are using.

Comment: What language is this?